# Series of data, how to determine if I have an abnormal spike?

Tags: python, change-point

I have a some simple chronological data as shown below. I'm new to stats but I have a math background. If I'm writing a Python script, how would I detect when I see a jump in value, eg starting around 2020-11-29 21:00:00:

```
2020-11-28 11:00:00     6
2020-11-28 12:00:00     4
2020-11-28 13:00:00    11
2020-11-28 14:00:00     8
2020-11-28 15:00:00     8
2020-11-28 16:00:00     3
2020-11-28 17:00:00     7
2020-11-28 18:00:00     2
2020-11-28 19:00:00     2
2020-11-28 20:00:00     6
2020-11-28 21:00:00     2
2020-11-28 22:00:00     9
2020-11-28 23:00:00    22
2020-11-29 00:00:00     5
2020-11-29 01:00:00     5
2020-11-29 02:00:00    15
2020-11-29 03:00:00     5
2020-11-29 04:00:00     8
2020-11-29 05:00:00    14
2020-11-29 06:00:00     5
2020-11-29 07:00:00    12
2020-11-29 08:00:00     7
2020-11-29 09:00:00     9
2020-11-29 10:00:00     2
2020-11-29 11:00:00     6
2020-11-29 12:00:00     7
2020-11-29 13:00:00     9
2020-11-29 14:00:00     8
2020-11-29 15:00:00     8
2020-11-29 16:00:00    11
2020-11-29 17:00:00     6
2020-11-29 18:00:00     2
2020-11-29 19:00:00     5
2020-11-29 20:00:00     5
2020-11-29 21:00:00    10
2020-11-29 22:00:00    15
2020-11-29 23:00:00    12
2020-11-30 00:00:00    12
2020-11-30 01:00:00    12
2020-11-30 02:00:00    17
2020-11-30 03:00:00    20
2020-11-30 04:00:00    21
2020-11-30 05:00:00     5
2020-11-30 06:00:00    26
2020-11-30 07:00:00    19
2020-11-30 08:00:00    20
2020-11-30 09:00:00    21
2020-11-30 10:00:00    25
2020-11-30 11:00:00    12
2020-11-30 12:00:00    18
2020-11-30 13:00:00    13
2020-11-30 14:00:00    19
2020-11-30 15:00:00    30
2020-11-30 16:00:00    21
2020-11-30 17:00:00    19
2020-11-30 18:00:00    22
2020-11-30 19:00:00    20
2020-11-30 20:00:00    33
2020-11-30 21:00:00    29
2020-11-30 22:00:00    29
2020-11-30 23:00:00    27
2020-12-01 00:00:00    30
2020-12-01 01:00:00    35
2020-12-01 02:00:00    35
2020-12-01 03:00:00    22
2020-12-01 04:00:00    25
2020-12-01 05:00:00    20
2020-12-01 06:00:00    16
2020-12-01 07:00:00    34
2020-12-01 08:00:00    29
2020-12-01 09:00:00    41
2020-12-01 10:00:00    24
2020-12-01 11:00:00    31
2020-12-01 12:00:00    31
2020-12-01 13:00:00    27
2020-12-01 14:00:00    32
2020-12-01 15:00:00    34
2020-12-01 16:00:00    26
2020-12-01 17:00:00    26
2020-12-01 18:00:00    32
2020-12-01 19:00:00    25
2020-12-01 20:00:00    28
2020-12-01 21:00:00    37
2020-12-01 22:00:00    27
2020-12-01 23:00:00    31
2020-12-02 00:00:00    24
2020-12-02 01:00:00    28
2020-12-02 02:00:00    28
2020-12-02 03:00:00    22
2020-12-02 04:00:00    15
2020-12-02 05:00:00    25
2020-12-02 06:00:00    16
2020-12-02 07:00:00    10
2020-12-02 08:00:00    19
2020-12-02 09:00:00    17
2020-12-02 10:00:00    26
2020-12-02 11:00:00    29
2020-12-02 12:00:00    23
2020-12-02 13:00:00    31
2020-12-02 14:00:00    29
2020-12-02 15:00:00    42
2020-12-02 16:00:00    36
2020-12-02 17:00:00    26
2020-12-02 18:00:00    27
2020-12-02 19:00:00    24
2020-12-02 20:00:00    28
2020-12-02 21:00:00    12
2020-12-02 22:00:00    14
2020-12-02 23:00:00    30
2020-12-03 00:00:00    19
2020-12-03 01:00:00    19
2020-12-03 02:00:00    45
2020-12-03 03:00:00    35
2020-12-03 04:00:00    28
2020-12-03 05:00:00    13
2020-12-03 06:00:00    23
2020-12-03 07:00:00    13
2020-12-03 08:00:00    16
2020-12-03 09:00:00    26
2020-12-03 10:00:00    20
2020-12-03 11:00:00    19
2020-12-03 12:00:00    33
2020-12-03 13:00:00    21
2020-12-03 14:00:00    38
2020-12-03 15:00:00    43
2020-12-03 16:00:00    40
2020-12-03 17:00:00    29
2020-12-03 18:00:00    28
2020-12-03 19:00:00    43
2020-12-03 20:00:00    36
2020-12-03 21:00:00    47
2020-12-03 22:00:00    19
2020-12-03 23:00:00    17
2020-12-04 00:00:00    24
2020-12-04 01:00:00    28
2020-12-04 02:00:00    22
2020-12-04 03:00:00    13
2020-12-04 04:00:00    26
2020-12-04 05:00:00    29
2020-12-04 06:00:00    28
2020-12-04 07:00:00    28
2020-12-04 08:00:00    16
2020-12-04 09:00:00    21
2020-12-04 10:00:00    26
2020-12-04 11:00:00    29
```

Comment: I would start off by plotting it first and then start looking into some statistical tests possibly

Comment: @Stochastic can you recommend some statistical tests that I can research that might work here?

Comment: I think it depends what your objective is. If you want to fit a time series model like an ARIMA model for example it might be feasible to fit an intervention where you see the "jump".

Comment: Research the threads with the [tag:change-point] tag.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good introductory tutorial for Python [here](https://techrando.com/2019/08/14/a-brief-introduction-to-change-point-detection-using-python/).  This includes statistical tests mainly for Normal distributed data.  I won't repeat the whole tutorial here but the authors suggest 3 ways of performing a changepoint analysis in Python.

If you want more advanced techniques then you may be better looking at rPy2 as I don't believe the functionality is currently available in Python (although plans are in the pipeline!).